# JIBX: Classes generated from maven codegen plugin : No unmarshaller for element

Tags: java, maven, xsd, code-generation, jibx

I use Jibx CodeGen maven Plugin to generate java sources and binding from xsd files.
I want to maintain several versions of the xsd in the same applications so I plan to generate to a different target package depending the version of the XSD.

JBix seems to generate java package based on the namespaces of the xsd files.

ie. for namespace `http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types` it generates package `org.jibx.example.generated.v30.types`

During maven build code generation seems to work and binding files are generated but during the binding phase, it says that Verification was a failure :

Sample of maven log

```
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.Bar
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.Foo
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.SpecificFoo
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v30.generic.Generic
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v31.bar.Bar
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v31.bar.SpecificBar
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v31.foo.Foo
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v31.foo.SpecificFoo
Generating code for mapping org.jibx.example.generated.v31.generic.Generic

Wrote 16 files

 org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.Bar output file size is 4365 bytes
Verification failure on class org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.Bar:
  VERIFIED_REJECTED
Repository.lookup() failed. FILE NOT FOUND?

 Found 10 methods:
  void marshal
  void JiBX_binding_v30_marshal_1_0
  org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.Bar JiBX_binding_v30_newinstance_1_0
  org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.Bar JiBX_binding_v30_unmarshal_1_0
  java.lang.String JiBX_getName
  void setSpecific
  org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar getSpecific
  void setGeneric
  org.jibx.example.generated.v30.generic.Generic getGeneric
  void unmarshal

 org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar output file size is 2056 bytes
Verification failure on class org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar:
  VERIFIED_REJECTED
Repository.lookup() failed. FILE NOT FOUND?

 Found 6 methods:
  java.lang.String getLabel
  void JiBX_binding_v30_marshal_1_0
  boolean JiBX_binding_v30_test_1_0
  org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar JiBX_binding_v30_newinstance_1_0
  org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar JiBX_binding_v30_unmarshal_1_0
  void setLabel

 org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.Foo output file size is 4365 bytes
Verification failure on class org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.Foo:
  VERIFIED_REJECTED
Repository.lookup() failed. FILE NOT FOUND?
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <jibx.version>1.2.4.3</jibx.version>
    <jibx.codegen.version>1.2.4.3</jibx.codegen.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.9.1</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype</id>
        <name>Sonatype Groups</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!-- ### Target JDK 1.6 ### -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <!-- #### Cleaning up generated sources #### -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>src-generated/src</directory>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*</include>
                        </includes>
                        <followSymlinks>false</followSymlinks>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jibx.codegen.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLocation>src/main/config</schemaLocation>
                <schemaBindingDirectory>src-generated/src</schemaBindingDirectory>
                <baseBindingDirectory>src-generated/src</baseBindingDirectory>
                <targetDirectory>src-generated/src</targetDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <!-- ### Generation of binding for versions 3.0 of XSD ### -->
                    <id>generate-java-code-from-schema-3.0</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLocation>src/main/config</schemaLocation>
                        <schemaBindingDirectory>src-generated/src</schemaBindingDirectory>
                        <baseBindingDirectory>src-generated/src</baseBindingDirectory>
                        <targetDirectory>src-generated/src</targetDirectory>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            <includeSchema>types-3.0.xsd</includeSchema>
                            <includeSchema>generic-3.0.xsd</includeSchema>
                            <includeSchema>foo-3.0.xsd</includeSchema>
                            <includeSchema>bar-3.0.xsd</includeSchema>
                        </includeSchemas>
                        <options>
                            <binding-file-name>binding-v30.xml</binding-file-name>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-java-code-from-schema-3.1</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema-codegen</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLocation>src/main/config</schemaLocation>
                        <schemaBindingDirectory>src-generated/src</schemaBindingDirectory>
                        <baseBindingDirectory>src-generated/src</baseBindingDirectory>
                        <targetDirectory>src-generated/src</targetDirectory>
                        <includeSchemas>
                            <includeSchema>types-3.1.xsd</includeSchema>
                            <includeSchema>generic-3.1.xsd</includeSchema>
                            <includeSchema>foo-3.1.xsd</includeSchema>
                            <includeSchema>bar-3.1.xsd</includeSchema>
                        </includeSchemas>
                        <options>
                            <binding-file-name>binding-v31.xml</binding-file-name>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile-binding</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bind</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>binding-v30.xml</include>
                            <include>binding-v31.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                        <load>true</load>
                        <validate>true</validate>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <verify>true</verify>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${build-helper-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src-generated/src</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

foo-3.0.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo"
    xmlns="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo" 
    xmlns:dgr="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/generic" 
    xmlns:tdr="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types"
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/generic"
        schemaLocation="generic-3.0.xsd" />
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types"
        schemaLocation="types-3.0.xsd" />
    <xs:element name="foo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation><![CDATA[ Documentation with french accentuation : éàç]]></xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="generic" type="dgr:generic" />
                <xs:element name="specific" type="specificFoo" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="specificFoo">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="label" type="label">
             <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>Label for Foo</xs:documentation>
               </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="dateFoo" type="tdr:dateDDMMYYYY" minOccurs="0">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Date of Foo</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:simpleType name="label">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="2" />
            <xs:maxLength value="255" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType> 
</xs:schema>
```

generic-3.0.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/generic"
    xmlns="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/generic"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:tdr="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types"
        schemaLocation="types-3.0.xsd" />
    <xs:complexType name="generic">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Generic data</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="type" type="tdr:typeCode">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Type for code</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>        
            <xs:element name="isValid" type="xs:boolean">
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:documentation>Flag that tells generic data is valid</xs:documentation>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>     
</xs:schema>
```

types-3.0.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tdr="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/types" elementFormDefault="unqualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:simpleType name="text">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Text</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="typeCode">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Text</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="dateDDMMYYYY">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Date au with format : DD/MM/YYYY</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:length value="10" />
            <xs:pattern value="[0-3][0-9]/[0-1][0-9]/(19|20)[0-9]{2}" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>     
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the generated binding (binding-v30.xml)

```
<binding xmlns:ns1="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/bar" xmlns:ns2="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo" xmlns:dgr="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/generic" name="binding_v30" package="org.jibx.example.generated.v30" trim-whitespace="true">
  <namespace uri="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/bar" prefix="ns1"/>
  <namespace uri="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo" prefix="ns2"/>
  <mapping class="org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.Bar" name="bar" ns="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/bar">
    <structure map-as="dgr:generic" get-method="getGeneric" set-method="setGeneric" name="generic"/>
    <structure map-as="ns1:specificBar" get-method="getSpecific" set-method="setSpecific" name="specific"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping abstract="true" type-name="ns1:specificBar" class="org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.SpecificBar">
    <value style="element" name="label" get-method="getLabel" set-method="setLabel"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping class="org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.Foo" name="foo" ns="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo">
    <structure map-as="dgr:generic" get-method="getGeneric" set-method="setGeneric" name="generic"/>
    <structure map-as="ns2:specificFoo" get-method="getSpecific" set-method="setSpecific" name="specific"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping abstract="true" type-name="ns2:specificFoo" class="org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.SpecificFoo">
    <value style="element" name="label" get-method="getLabel" set-method="setLabel"/>
    <value style="element" name="dateFoo" get-method="getDateFoo" set-method="setDateFoo" usage="optional"/>
  </mapping>
  <mapping abstract="true" type-name="dgr:generic" class="org.jibx.example.generated.v30.generic.Generic">
    <value style="element" name="type" get-method="getType" set-method="setType"/>
    <value style="element" name="isValid" get-method="isIsValid" set-method="setIsValid"/>
  </mapping>
</binding>
```

I wrote A Junit test to make sure that jibx can instanciate the factory for my binded objects and unmarshall xml file against it.

Junit unit test : FooTest.java

```
@Test
public void testFoo1()
{  
    IBindingFactory foo30Factory = null;
    try
    {
        foo30Factory = BindingDirectory.getFactory("binding_v30", Foo.class);
    }
    catch (JiBXException e)
    {
        String l_msg = "Cannot create factory ";
        LOGGER.error(l_msg, e);
        Assert.fail(l_msg + e.getMessage());
    }

    IUnmarshallingContext unmarshmallingContext = null;
    try
    {
        unmarshmallingContext = foo30Factory.createUnmarshallingContext();
    }
    catch (JiBXException e)
    {
        String l_msg = "Cannot create unmarshmalling context ";
        LOGGER.error(l_msg, e);
        Assert.fail(l_msg + e.getMessage());
    }

    String l_xmlFileToTest = "/xml/foo1.xml";
    LOGGER.info("Loading file : " + l_xmlFileToTest);
    InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(l_xmlFileToTest);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    Foo l_fooObtained = null;
    try
    {
        l_fooObtained = (Foo) unmarshmallingContext.unmarshalDocument(buffer);
    }
    catch (JiBXException e)
    {
        String l_msg = "Cannot instanciate object for class " + Foo.class;
        LOGGER.error(l_msg, e);
        Assert.fail(l_msg + e.getMessage());
    }

    Assert.assertNotNull("l_coeaObtenu ne doit pas etre null", l_fooObtained);
    }
```

foo1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <foo>
        <generic>
            <type>12345</type>
            <isValid>1</isValid>
        </generic>
        <specific>
            <label>Label example</label>
            <dateFoo>01/01/2015</dateFoo>
        </specific>
    </foo>
```

I got this stacktrace when I run it:  No unmarshaller for element "generic"

```
ERROR FooTest - Cannot instanciate object for class class org.jibx.example.generated.v30.foo.Foo
org.jibx.runtime.JiBXException: No unmarshaller for element "generic" (line 5, col 14)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:2754)
        at org.jibx.runtime.impl.UnmarshallingContext.unmarshalDocument(UnmarshallingContext.java:2914)
        at org.jibx.example.generated.v30.bar.FooTest.testFoo1(FooTest.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I was missing namepace declaration in the xml I wanted to consume.
It works with a correctly shaped one as the following one :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
        <foo:foo xmlns:foo="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.jibx.org/generated/v30/foo foo-3.0.xsd">
            <generic>
                <type>12345</type>
                <isValid>1</isValid>
            </generic>
            <specific>
                <label>Label example</label>
                <dateFoo>01/01/2015</dateFoo>
            </specific>
        </foo:foo>
```

Answer (score 0):

Marc,

Take a look at the example in the JiBX schema library for the

[Opentravel schema Library](http://jibx.org/schema-library/site.html#opentravel.org)

It is very similar to your problem Many schemas with the same namespace need to be bound to different java packages.

Also, I would suggest that you use a newer version of JiBX, such as 1.2.6

Cheers!

Don

Comment: I am not using 1.2.6 version yet because code generation does not encode java files using UTF-8 encoding (but uses locale encoding :french) whoch cause compilation errors. Even if I run mvn command with encode flag or use UTF-8 encoding in pom.xml. I will take a look at these examples. Thank you for the advice.